# how can I add a row to each other very fast in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

So basically i need D2 and E2 added together and then E2 replaced with the sum and then the same for each column after which then would be E2 and F2 and then replace F2 with the sum of those i want a formula with this i believe it is possible just i am not skilled enough in google sheets for that and this would also go for every row below but i didnt give examples of those above

[image: CSV File]

I have tried using =SUM() but i cant get it to do what i want without alot of time involved in copy and pasting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm unaware of a formula option that will allow you to replace cell contents that your are using to calculate. You can create a separate table that would calculate the running/cumulative SUM for each row.

I don't have an array option so it will require dragging.

in L1, paste `={D1:J1}`

in L2, paste `=IF(D2="",,SUM($D2:D2))`

drag L1 over to R1 and down to as far down as your values go/may go

if you want to use your original table, you can clear column K and in K1, paste `={"Total";ArrayFormula(IF(R2:R="",,R2:R))}` (this formula can also go in S1 if you want to use/view the new table with a "TOTAL" column).

Comment: Thank you this works for my needs as i just need something quick and easy

Comment: one last thing any idea why it would be not be allowing it to go above 24:00:00 since this is just meant to be a HH:MM:SS format no matter how many hours

Comment: try formatting as duration: Format >> Number >> Duration